# "Authentication Client ID is not configured", I am making a react SPA of a microsoft login page for my application using azure. What is my mistake?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure, azure-web-app-service

This is what I have done:

I added a `.env` file on the root Level:

```
REACT_APP_AZURE_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_APP_CLIENT_ID = (Client ID)
```

Then I added three files under `src` subfolder.

Then I changed the code of `app.tsx` to a new one as I was asked.

[This is the tutorial I am following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/single-page-application-azure-login-button-sdk-msal).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/single-page-application-azure-login-button-sdk-msal

Comment: put some of ur code, so people can understand wat ur doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I don't change anythings in project. Just paste client_id into `.env` file.

And I also follow the offical doc, create app regidtration, add spa and so on.

[image]

[image]

**My test steps:**

1. [Download sample peoject code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/js-e2e-client-azure-login-button) from the link you provided.
2. Open it by vscode, run cmd `npm i`.
3. Copy and paste clientid into `.env` file.

   [image]
4. Then excute cmd `npm run start`. It works fine.

   [image]

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I was also following the MS tutorial and encountered the same problem.
What I needed to do was:

1. Stop the development server (by pressing [CTRL]+[C])
2. Run `npm i` (I don't now if this step is needed)
3. Start the development server again: `npm run start`